# How to execute a facebook notification after a certain amount of time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, push-notification

I am new to Facebook development and I am wondering how I can delay execution of an app notification by a given amount of time (days)?
At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications or via Google I can't find anything regarding delaying notifications, everything seems to happen immediately.

What I am trying to achieve is that when a facebook app is loaded, I will add a notification to be executed in x days so that the user is reminded of returning to the app then.

I will do this every time the app loads, overwriting the existing notification that was still to be executed.

By that, the user will get the notification only when he really is not logged in for x days.

I'd like to solve that through Facebook alone and not through timers on the server. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to send delayed notifications, you need to do that on your own. For example, with a Cron Job that checks for the timestamp of the last login every day. Creating a new delayed notification (and deleting the old one) whenever the user logs in would be a weird solution anyway...Those things are usually done with Cron Jobs, there is no need to use the Facebook API when you don´t need it.

Comment: Thx. This would be the way local notifications on Android or iOS work.